# IN CIFAR 10 DATASET

Tags: keras, mlp

After building up the mlp using

```
## building a mlp model
model=Sequential()
model.add(Dense(25,input_shape=(10,),activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(100,input_shape=(10,),activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(150,input_shape=(16,),activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(10,input_shape=(10,),activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='Adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
```

When I'm trying to fit the model using:

```
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10,validation_data=(x_test,y_test))`
```

I'm getting this error:

> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in 
>         1 # Training the MLP on the 2D data
>   ----> 2 model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10,validation_data=(x_test,y_test))
>
> ~\anaconda\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, **kwargs)
>       950             sample_weight=sample_weight,
>       951             class_weight=class_weight,
>   --> 952             batch_size=batch_size)
>       953         # Prepare validation data.
>       954         do_validation = False
>
> ~\anaconda\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in _standardize_user_data(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight, check_array_lengths, batch_size)
>       749             feed_input_shapes,
>       750             check_batch_axis=False,  # Don't enforce the batch size.
>   --> 751             exception_prefix='input')
>       752 
>       753         if y is not None:
>
> ~\anaconda\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_utils.py in standardize_input_data(data, names, shapes, check_batch_axis, exception_prefix)
>       136                             ': expected ' + names[i] + ' to have shape ' +
>       137                             str(shape) + ' but got array with shape ' +
>   --> 138                             str(data_shape))
>       139     return data
>       140
>
> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_29_input to have shape (10,) but got array with shape (3072,)

Can someone please help me find the mistake?

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is the `input_shape` argument you are using, firstly that is the wrong shape and you should only provide an input shape for your first layer.

For example

Let's import the CIFAR 10 data from Keras

```
from __future__ import print_function
import keras
from keras.datasets import cifar10
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
import os

num_classes = 10

# The data, split between train and test sets:
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = cifar10.load_data()
print('x_train shape:', x_train.shape)
print(x_train.shape[0], 'train samples')
print(x_test.shape[0], 'test samples')

# Convert class vectors to binary class matrices.
y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)

input_shape = x_train.shape[1:]
print('input_shape: ', input_shape)
```

> x_train shape: (50000, 32, 32, 3) 
>   50000 train samples 
>   10000 test samples 
>   input_shape: (32, 32, 3)

Now we can define our model. Note that I only use the input_shape in the first layer and furthermore, if you want to use a Dense layer as your first layer then you should flatten your inputs first.

```
model=Sequential()
model.add(Flatten(input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Dense(25,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(100,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(150,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(10,activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='Adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
```

You can use this to see your model

```
model.summary()
```

Now you can fit your model

```
model.fit(x_train, 
          y_train, 
          epochs=10,
          validation_data=(x_test,y_test))
```

---

Since CIFAR 10 is comprised of image data I would not recommend you use Dense layers early in your model. You should rather use a Convolutional Neural Network (CNN). These layers act as a filter which extracts features from a neighborhood region of the image. This reduces the number of model parameters which will lead to better performance. From the Keras docs found [here](https://keras.io/examples/cifar10_cnn/):

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same',
                 input_shape=x_train.shape[1:]))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(512))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(num_classes))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
```